# A certain _secret_ hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

I admit the requirements of this specific hat are confusing. They mention one specific action that by itself is quite easy to do - but is considered "a hat material" only if there 5 actions of another kind "approving" it.

The question is, should these fives be done at any point in time - or just before someone else made the same beneficial action? And what if I'll be the one of those 'confirmers' - will it be counted still, or not? )

*I'm sure that most of those who read this will get the point; for all the others, I tried my best not to spoit it too much. )*

Comment: Did you already perform the aforementioned action on this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now that I got it, I know the truth: the confirming actions are counted without any additional conditions (yes, your own action is counted too).

Comment: yes, that's how I see it.